# Como fazer replace com o caracter '\' com RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex

Preciso que o caracter '\' (Reverse Solidus) seja incluído com o valor do grupo capturado.

Exemplo:

Na frase **assets/pdf/regulamento_demais_ddds_ Oi Mod.pdf**, preciso que o **trecho**

> /pdf

seja substituído por

```
\/pdf\/
```

formando a frase

```
assets\/pdf\/regulamento_demais_ddds_Oi_Mod.pdf
```

Expressão regular funcionando: https://regexr.com/3nr2m

Exemplo Código:

```
//Expressão regular aplicada 
(\/(?=pdf|images)pdf|\/images)

//Texto para achar o grupo de substituição
const texto = 'assets/pdf/regulamento_Oi_Mod.pdf assets/images/oi-mod-tela-controle-2x.gif'

 const resultado = texto.replace(/(\/(?=pdf|images)pdf|\/images)/g, '/\$1\/');//Replace para incluir '\' no valor capturado
```

O problema é que o caracter '\' não é reconhecido.

Código:

```js
//Texto para achar o grupo de substituição
const texto = 'assets/pdf/regulamento_Oi_Mod.pdf assets/images/oi-mod-tela-controle-2x.gif'
          
//Replace para incluir '\' no valor capturado
const resultado = texto.replace(/(\/(?=pdf|images)pdf|\/images)/g, '/\$1\/');

console.log(resultado)
```

Comment: Use `texto.replace(/(\/(?=pdf|images)pdf|\/images)/g, '\\$1\\');`

Comment: Uma [demo no Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/EJBcqA/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var texto = 'assets/pdf/regulamento_Oi_Mod.pdf assets/images/oi-mod-tela-controle-2x.gif';

var mapObj = {
   "/pdf/":"\\/pdf\\/",
   "/images/":"\\/images\\/"
};

var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(mapObj).join("|"),"gi");
texto = texto.replace(re, function(matched){
  return mapObj[matched];
});

console.log(texto);
```

> Dessa forma acho que fica mais fácil incluir mais ocorrências.

Basta incluir mais ocorrências na `var mapObj`

Exemplo:

```js
var texto = 'assets/pdf/regulamento_Oi_Mod.pdf assets/images/blabla /mais ocorrencias/oi-mod-tela-controle-2x.gif';

 var mapObj = {
   "/pdf/":"\\/pdf\\/",
   "/images/":"\\/images\\/",
   "/mais ocorrencias/":"\\/mais ocorrencias\\/"
};

var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(mapObj).join("|"),"gi");
texto = texto.replace(re, function(matched){
  return mapObj[matched];
});

console.log(texto);
```

Comment: Realmente fica prático.

Comment: Me resolveu outro problema que iria começar a pesquisar agora. Ficou muito bom. Obrigada @LeoCaracciolo!

Answer (score 1):

Olá, para incluir o caractere "\" basta utilizar o método replace do objeto String, da seguinte maneira:

```js
var texto = 'assets/pdf/regulamento_Oi_Mod.pdf assets/images/oi-mod-tela-controle-2x.gif';
texto = texto.replace(/\//g, '\\/');
console.log(texto);
```

O código acima substituirá toda ocorrência dos caracteres "`/`" por "`\/`".

Comment: Mas ela que apenas nas ocorrências de pdf e images.

Comment: obrigada Diego, mas precisava que fossem só nas ocorrências de pdf e images como o @dvd mencionou.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa escapar as barras invertidas no `replace` com outra barra invertida:

```
'\\$1\\'
 ↑   ↑
barras invertidas de escape
```

```js
//Texto para achar o grupo de substituição
const texto = 'assets/pdf/regulamento_Oi_Mod.pdf assets/images/oi-mod-tela-controle-2x.gif'
          
//Replace para incluir '\' no valor capturado
const resultado = texto.replace(/(\/(?=pdf|images)pdf|\/images)/g, '\\$1\\');

console.log(resultado)
```

Comment: Vou te contar, essa pergunta é uma barra!! :)

Comment: boa piada, @LeoCaracciolo! hahaha

Comment: Obrigada @dvd, funcionou perfeitamente! =)

Answer (score -1):

```
var texto = "assets/pdf/regulamento_Oi_Mod.pdf assets/images/oi-mod-tela-controle-2x.gif";
texto.replace(/\/((?=pdf|images)pdf|images)\//g, "\\/$1\\/")
console.log(texto);
```